# Console output is changing behavior dependent to type of definition

Tags: typescript

I defined two `Product` object with different method and added them to `products` array. When I want to dump content of `products` array. I realized something interesting.

```
class Product {
    constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string, public category?: string, public price?: number) { }
}

let products: Array<Product> = new Array<Product>();
let newProduct: Product = { id: 1, name: "Iphone 6", category: "Telephone", price: 4000 };
let newProduct2: Product = new Product(2, "Iphone 5", "Telephone", 5000);

products.push(newProduct);
products.push(newProduct2);
console.log(products);
```

Console output is:

```
[
  { id: 2, name: 'Iphone 6', category: 'Telephone', price: 4000 },
  Product {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Iphone 5',
    category: 'Telephone',
    price: 5000
  }
]
```

Console behavior is changing dependent to type of defination. After all, objects are belong to same class. What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: The behavior you're experiencing is actually opposite of what you've described. Type annotations do not affect any runtime behavior and that's exactly why you're seeing what you're seeing, because of the objects are not of the same type

Comment: It's very important to note that the TypeScript's type system is structural and fully erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both objects, but they're not the same—`newProduct` is not an instance of `Product`, while `newProduct2` is, because the latter is instantiated using the `Product` class:

```
console.log(newProduct instanceOf Product);  // false
console.log(newProduct2 instanceOf Product); // true
```

And the reason why the console log looks "different" is only because the console will also log the name of the class the object is instantiated with.

Comment: Can I say `Product` isn't mean anything for Typescript in definition of `newProduct` ?

Comment: It does mean something in both JS and TS. It will not pass the `instanceOf Product` check.